# Fail to create temp files in Oracle 10g

Tags: linux, oracle, files

My disk is full so I delete oracle temp files to gain space. I use oragle 10g with CentOS release 4.4 Operation System.

First Search temp files

```
SELECT tablespace_name, file_name, bytes FROM dba_temp_files WHERE tablespace_name = 'TEMP';
```

Delete temp files (6 files)

```
alter database TEMPFILE '/oracle/oradata/ral/temp0X.dbf' drop including datafiles;
```

but now i can´t create one file

```
ALTER TABLESPACE temp ADD TEMPFILE '/oracle/oradata/ral/temp01.dbf' SIZE 512m AUTOEXTEND ON NEXT 250m MAXSIZE 2048m;

ERROR

ALTER TABLESPACE temp ADD TEMPFILE '/oracle/oradata/ral/temp01.dbf' SIZE 512m AUTOEXTEND ON NEXT 250m MAXSIZE 2048m
Informe de error:
Error SQL: ORA-01119: error create database file '/oracle/oradata/ral/temp01.dbf'
ORA-27044: no se ha podido escribir el bloque de cabecera del archivo
Linux-x86_64 Error: 28: No space left on device
Additional information: 3
01119. 00000 -  "error in creating database file '%s'"
*Cause:    Usually due to not having enough space on the device.
*Action:
```

I have free space but I can not create the file.
What is the problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Run `df` on the box itself.  Are you sure that other log files or applications are not filling the disk?

Comment: [root@server bin]# df  (67829336 - 64939240 = 2890096 KB)
S.ficheros  /dev/hda      1k Block 67829336   Use 64939240

Comment: Start looking around for other culprits.  What else runs on the server?  Do you have any files in /var/log the are filling rapidly?  Is this server usually near capacity?

Comment: Althought disk is not full, availability of free space is 0. I still looking culprits. Thanx

Comment: What do you mean the disk is not full?  P.s. I'm converting this to an answer, please accept if you think that this has answered your question.

Comment: I have a 65G disk. In this momen a use 62 G but avaliable space is 0. df  - h command Total   65G
Use   62G
Avalibility     0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run `df` on the box -- your disk likely does not have free space available.

See this related StackOverflow answer regarding Oracle not resulting in the freeing of disk space: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9432465/reclaim-the-space-after-a-large-delete-in-oracle

Answer (score 0):

Some amount of space is reserved for the system (root user) by default.

The following will set reserved space to 0 blocks, so that all free space will be available to users (and thus Oracle).

```
tune2fs -m 0 /dev/sdb1
```

Replace `sdb1` with the device in question.

Running `df` should now confirm that the space is indeed available for use.

This is probably not advisable on the root or /var filesystems, also know that completely filling up any ext filesystem may cause performance issues down the road, due to fragmentation.